# Build .jar with .class and others .jar

Tags: java, cmd, jar

I have the .class generated in compiling a .java file. The whole code of my program is in a main within my .java. With this, from the command line I want to create a .jar to execute directly from the command line with JAVA-jar. In my program I use two external .jar files, which I have in the same folder as the other files, but I do not know how to put them in the process of creating or executing the .jar. My script contains the following:

```
  jar  -cf CantidadAnio.jar CantidadAnio.class
  @ECHO.
  @ECHO.
  jar cmf temp.mf CantidadAnio.jar CantidadAnio.class
  JAVA-jar CantidadAnio.jar cantidadanio.csv
```

temp.mf:
    Main-Class: CantidadAnio
    Sealed: true

The problem is in the execution of .jar, which does not recognize the classes and methods that are defined in the two external .jar

I have also tried to generate and run the .class from the .java, but at the time of execution it shows me the error: "Could not find or load main class CantidadAnio"

For this I have used the script:

```
 javac -cp "opencsv-3.9.jar;ChartDirector.jar" CantidadAnio.java
java -cp "opencsv-3.9.jar;ChartDirector.jar" CantidadAnio "cantidadanio.csv"
```

Comment: In your second example (running the `.class` file directly) you forgot to add the directory where the class file resides to your classpath (like `java -cp "jar1.jar;jar2.jar;." Class`). If you want to run with just a simple `java -jar foo.jar`, you'll have to build a "fat jar", i.e. extract your dependency jars and repackage all classes into a single jar

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: I recommend against the "unpack/repack" method of delivering third-party JARs. It defeats the purpose of JAR files, muddies your code, possibly violates software license terms, and is a deployment mess. Go with the more conventional packaging strategies.

Comment: The only solution I have found to this problem is to unzip each .jar file.  Either manually place the contents inside your project, or include them in your `javac` command.  Then use the folder name in your -cp or manifest class-path, instead of each jar.  In your final .jar file they need to appear as regular, not-in-jars, .class files.  If you have a lot of .jar files you'll probably want to use a tool to create a so-called 'fat jar'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea to package third-party JARs into one's own custom JAR. Read up on the JAR manifest, which specifies the classpath for a `java -jar` execution, among other things. The usual approach is to package the third-party JARs with your JAR in the same directory, or in a `lib/` subdirectory, and use either Java Web Start/JNLP or a ZIP file to deliver the whole package. In the end you have a deployment that might look like this:

```
deployment_directory/
|
|-- your.jar
|
|-- lib/
    |
    |-- third_party.jar
    |
    |-- other_third_party.jar
```

Then you use the `Class-Path:` manifest entry in your JAR to tell where the other JARs are, relative to the deployment directory.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javaws.html#BABHGIBB
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jar.html#BGBEJEEG
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html

Comment: he is using the -cp command which overrides the manifest and works exactly the same way.  Whatever classpath he puts in the manifest, he can put the same thing in -cp.  Telling him to use a manifest file is not the answer.